# how to extract xpath of an web element by element id/class/tag etc. through Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am new to this. I want to extract the xPath of an element and store it. Now I can find the element by its id or class name as they are unique.

Is there a way to extract the xPath of any element by identifying it thorough other attributes?

Thanks,
Adhiraj

Answer (score 0):

You must first understand that there is no "the" with Xpath. Every object has many xpaths. So when you say you want to get "the xpath", you can understand that the question does not make sense.

Tools such as Firebug provide you with 'an' Xpath, presumably based on an algorithm which finds the first unique Xpath. Often this generated Xpath is complex, brittle and not suitable for automation

Comment: Thanks Robbie, you have cleared up possibly the very root level concept of xPath. Appreciated.